# Plotting fit in Matplotlib. Value error: x and y must have the same first dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, model

I am trying to plot data, I have uploaded the file as a txt, labelled each of the columns Z, Y and X and the used numpy to get the data in an array. When I come to plot the data I only get 2 data points (there should be 1119 data points) and when I try to run the inital fit I get this error warning.

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1119,) and (1,)
```

If anyone knows what the issue is I would really appreciate the help, I only started learning python a few weeks ago so I'm not great at reading quite technical texts.

My code is:

```
myfile =open()

data = pd.read_csv(myfile, sep='\t', header=None, names=['Z','Y', 'X'])
data1= data.to_numpy()

pmodel = Model(JanesPowerLaw)

params = pmodel.make_params(A=5.0, x0=2.0, m=2)
xd = (data1[2])    
yd = (data1[1])
yinit = pmodel.eval(params, x=xd) 
nan_policy='omit'
result = pmodel.fit(yd, params=params, x=xd)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xd, yd, 'bo')
plt.plot(xd, result.init_fit, 'k--', label='initial fit')
```

Thank you again in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), rather than the entirety of your code. This makes it easy for others to reproduce and solve your problem.

Comment: The key thing is the shape of your `data1`. Have you looked at it?

Comment: ahh thank you so much! I can now get it to correctly plot the data points:)

Comment: I'm not trying to plot the initial fit curve and having a similar problem (error message 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1119,) and (1,)' I think this is because this line of code isn't working  'yinit = pmodel.eval(params, x=xd)' . Do you know how the eval function works? I think that may be part of the problem